# How do I display the next month in a Microsoft Word field?

Tags: date, ms-word, fieldcodes, word-field

I'm needing to display the name of the month after the current month in a Word 2003 document.

It's fairly easy to display the current month:

```
{ DATE \@ "MMMM" }
```

At the time of this writing, this displays: September

What I'm wanting to display is October...and for the life of me I cannot work out what needs to be done.

I've been trying to follow the advice on [addbalance](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm) but without much luck:

```
{ = { Date \@ "MMMM" } + 1 }
```

Does anyone know what command I need to write to be able to accomplish this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a QUOTE field to do so. The documentation contains an example to **[show the previous month](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-quote-field-HP005186186.aspx)**, which could be easily modified to show the next month:

```
{ QUOTE "1.{ IF { DATE \@ "M" }=12 "1" "{ = { DATE \@ "M" }+1} }.2010" \@ "MMMM"}
```

Note that you probably need to change the format of the date generated by the IF field to match your current locale settings. The part `{ IF { DATE \@ "M" }=12 "1" "{ = { DATE \@ "M" }+1} }` is used to get the next month and should be used to generate a complete (imaginary) date, e.g. `1.<nextmonth>.2010` or `<nextmonth>/01/05`.

Comment: Awesome! That worked, though I had to change it to { QUOTE { IF { DATE \@ "M" } = 12 "1" "1/{= { DATE \@ "M" } + 1 }/03" \@ "MMMM"}} in order to have it work in Australia

Comment: @mezoid: I noticed there was a bug in the sample provided by Microsoft. It doesn't work for December/January. See my update for a fix.

Comment: I tested it out, and you were right, it does have a bug in it...and I've tested your updated solution and it works great. Thanks so much for that! I wish I could give you 100 points!

Answer (score 0):

ah yes but what if you want to calculate a calendar month ahead which spans a new year, e.g. it goes from Dec 2020 to Jan 2021 automatically? This formula doesn't handle that due to a static year and couldn't handle a new year either with a static one.

Comment: Note this is more of a *comment* rather than an *answer*. At 50 reputation, you can leave comments. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment